# Center nested tables in html Email

Tags: html, html-table, html-email

How can I center the all child tables in the middle of the main parent table? What's the best way the add this blue bar between each headline with 10px margin or padding on the side between headlines?

```html
<table width="600" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="content">
        <tr>
          <td style="color: #007cb0;font-weight: bold; text-align: center; font-size: 12px;">headline one
            <br />headline</td>
          <td width="30" align="center"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/3x30/007cb0" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="content">
        <tr>
          <td style="color: #007cb0;font-weight: bold; text-align: center; font-size: 12px;">headline two
            <br />headline</td>
          <td width="30" align="center"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/3x30/007cb0" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="content">
        <tr>
          <td style="color: #007cb0;font-weight: bold; text-align: center; font-size: 12px;">headline three
            <br />headline</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a parent table around the smaller tables, give it a width and center it. You can give the table a width if you want (total of all child tables) `width="285"` in this case or go without the width, either works. Try the code below:

```html
<table width="600" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" align="center">
        <tr>
          <td>
            
            <table border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="content">
        <tr>
          <td style="color: #007cb0;font-weight: bold; text-align: center; font-size: 12px;">headline one
            <br />headline</td>
          <td width="30" align="center"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/3x30/007cb0" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="content">
        <tr>
          <td style="color: #007cb0;font-weight: bold; text-align: center; font-size: 12px;">headline two
            <br />headline</td>
          <td width="30" align="center"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/3x30/007cb0" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="content">
        <tr>
          <td style="color: #007cb0;font-weight: bold; text-align: center; font-size: 12px;">headline three
            <br />headline</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

One thing i noticed after doing this is if you make the template responsive you dont have to worry about the menu as it will stack by itself.

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: I need some help on email im working on, it has some problems on (google mail and outlook Pc), can you help me ?

Comment: Its me syfer.darknight at gmail

Answer (score 1):

```css
td {
  border-right: 4px solid #007cb0;
}

td:last-child {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" align="center">
  <tr>
  
<td style="color: #007cb0;font-weight: bold; text-align: center; font-size: 12px;">headline one<br />headline</td>
 
 <td style="color: #007cb0;font-weight: bold; text-align: center; font-size: 12px;">headline two<br />headline</td>


<td style="color: #007cb0;font-weight: bold; text-align: center; font-size: 12px;">headline three<br />headline</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: `nth-child` doesnt work well in some email clients like Outlook. Everything has to be inline for email clients like these.